# Is there a classify function for Scikit learn classifiers?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

I've been using NTLK classifiers to train datasets and classify single record. 
For training the records I use this function,

```
nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(train_set)
```

For classifying a single record,

```
nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.classify(record)
```

where, "record" is the variable name.

In Scikit classifiers, for training dataset, the function used is,

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
classifier = RandomForestClassifier()
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

What is the function to classify single record in scikit learn classifiers? i.e., is there something like this classifier.classify() ?

Predict method only classifies for whole test set converted into a sparse matrix vector, like y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)

```
y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)
```

I couldn't classify for a single record; I get this error :

```
File "C:\Users\HSR\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", 
line 433, in check_array array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, 
copy=copy) ValueError: could not convert string to float: This is a bot
```

If predict can be used to classify a single record, then how to do it?

Comment: you're looking for `predict()` method [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.predict)

Comment: No, predict method only classifies for whole test set converted into a sparse matrix vector, like _y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)_ . I couldn't classify for a single record; I get this error :  

File "C:\Users\HSR\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 433, in check_array
    array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)

ValueError: could not convert string to float: This is a bot

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a method that helps you to predict which class your data would fall in, I believe,

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
classifier = RandomForestClassifier()
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
classifier.predict(record)
```

would help. To know more about the available APIs, please follow this [link to the documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html).

It looks like, you are looking for a text classifier. Here is a `scikit-learn` [example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html#training-a-classifier) of a text classifier. The page gives a thorough introduction to working with text data in `scikit-learn`.

Comment: I tried it, 

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
classifier = RandomForestClassifier()
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)

record = 'This is a bot'
classi = classifier.predict(record)

The error:

  File "C:\Users\HSR\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 433, in check_array
    array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)

ValueError: could not convert string to float: This is a bot

Comment: That is because, classier cannot directly take in a string. From the error, I assume you are using strings directly for classification. However, the documentation says that,
`Internally, its dtype will be converted to dtype=np.float32. If a sparse matrix is provided, it will be converted into a sparse csr_matrix.`

This means that, you have to encode your text into some vectors and then run the classier over it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply all of the same preprocessing that you applied to your training data, sklearn classifiers don't know what you did to turn your text into training data. However, this can be done using sklearn's pipelines. `predict` does also expect an array, but you can pass it an array of one sample.